# Given $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin(x)=x - \frac{x^3}{6}+R(x)$, show that $0<R(x)<\frac{x^5}{120}$ (Taylors Remainder)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin(x)=x - \frac{x^3}{6}+R(x)$, show that $0<R(x)<\frac{x^5}{120}$ (Taylors Remainder).

Attempt at solution: We apply Taylors remainder formula on the following:
$$f(x)=P_3(x)+E_3(x)$$
As the forth derivative of $\sin(x)$ is zero, we consider $E_4(x)$.
$$R(x)=E_4(x)=\frac{f^5(s)}{5
!}x^5=\frac{\cos(s)}{120}x^5$$
Where $s \in [0,x]$. However, this means that $R(x)$ could be equal to $\frac{x^5}{120}$. I suspect that if we can instead say $s \in (0,x)$, it would be clearer that the inequality would follow (as $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$). My book has been rather unclear if s are interior points or not, simply stating "s is between x and a". But I suspect they are as the formula follows from the MVT. Lastly, is my reasoning to why we consider $E_4$ as opposed to $E_3$ acceptable, or are there better justifications?

Comment: A minor note: You actually need $f(x)=P_4(x)+E_4(x)$ since $E_3(x)$ involves the fourth power of $x$, not the fifth. Simply state you're applying the theorem for $n=4$, not $n=3$.

Comment: @bjorn93 this I suppose is valid as we have $0x^4$

Answer (score 1):

Taylor Lagrange theorem states that $s \in (0,x)$ which enables to conclude immediately. And yes, you can use $E_4$ instead of $E_3$ as $\sin$ is an odd map.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with an odd map?

Comment: By definition, a map such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$.